# DirectX 11.2 Error: X3501: 'main' entry point not found

Tags: c++, directx, shader, directx-11

I have been learning DirectX 11.2 lately from a Tutorial pack from Microsoft.
I am up to the 2nd tutorial where you create a triangle using shaders. However there is an error when I compile that is really bugging me and I have no idea how to fix it. error X3501: 'main' entry point not found, but what I don't understand is the fact that I do have the main entry point.

Here is my main function.

```
[Platform::MTAThread]
int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^)
{
    auto frameworkViewSource = ref new Direct3DFrameworkViewSource();
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::Run(frameworkViewSource);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the correct entry point and shader model in VS

Take a look at this page http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/51859322-fc36-4946-b4cb-b5971fcaa9e5/fxc-error-x3501-main-entrypoint-not-found?forum=wingameswithdirectx